# Is there a way to add chrome extension capabilites to PWA?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, progressive-web-apps

I have just created a chrome extension with certain features and I was wondering if it is possible to add some of these features inside a PWA, for example is it possible to take a screenshot with chrome.tabs or even have a content script inside a PWA??

Comment: No, `chrome` API is for chrome extensions.

Comment: For better understanding, you should read chrome documentation - https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9658361?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop